# gform_after_submission does not fire after form is submitted

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have tested my custom function, which works correctly on it's own when the form id and entry id are provided.  But it never seems to fire when a form is submitted.

I am using the action `add_action( 'gform_after_submission_14', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );`

My form id is 14.

How can I troubleshoot this or correct the issue?

My code is:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_14', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );
function after_submission($entry, $form){
    
    global $wpdb;
    include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/custom_config.php';
    $data = RGFormsModel::get_lead($entry);
    $eid = $data['id'];
    $user_id = $data['created_by'];
    $hotel = $data['33'];
    $flight = $data['39'];
    $car = $data['38'];
    $parking = $data['37'];
    $entertainment = $data['36'];
    $other = $data['35'];
    
    if($hotel!=''): 
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO reimbursements ( user_id, eid, amount, type ) VALUES ( '$user_id', '$eid', '$hotel',  'hotel' )");
        print_r($link);
    endif;  
    if($flight!=''):    
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO reimbursements ( user_id, eid, amount, type ) VALUES ( '$user_id', '$eid', '$flight',  'flight' )");
    endif;
    if($car!=''):   
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO reimbursements ( user_id, eid, amount, type ) VALUES ( '$user_id', '$eid', '$car',  'car' )");
    endif;
    if($parking!=''):   
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO reimbursements ( user_id, eid, amount, type ) VALUES ( '$user_id', '$eid', '$parking',  'parking' )");
    endif;
    if($entertainment!=''): 
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO reimbursements ( user_id, eid, amount, type ) VALUES ( '$user_id', '$eid', '$entertainment',  'entertainment' )");
    endif;
    if($other!=''): 
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO reimbursements ( user_id, eid, amount, type ) VALUES ( '$user_id', '$eid', '$other',  'other' )");
    endif;

mysqli_close($link);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

`$data = RGFormsModel::get_lead($entry);`

`$entry` is already an array that is in use.

So rather than define them again as I did:
`$eid = $data['id'];`
I should have used:
`$eid = $entry['id'];`

The bigger part of this solution was figuring out the ability to troubleshoot it.

For that, I did the following:

1. Add `GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): running.' );` to the top of the function.
2. Enable logging as explained here (https://docs.gravityforms.com/logging-and-debugging/#enabling-logging)
3. View the error log of 'Gravity Forms Core' at 'Forms->Settings->Logging'  This requires that 'logging' is check marked at the time the test is run.